# Remove string starting with something

Tags: php, regex

How can I do the following with php?

This is my example:
`http://www.example.com/index.php?&xx=okok&yy=no&bb=525252`

I want remove this part: `&yy=no&bb=525252`

I just want this result:
`http://www.example.com/index.php?&xx=okok`

I tried this :

```
$str = 'bla_string_bla_bla_bla';
echo preg_replace('/bla_/', '', $str, 1); ;
```

but this not what I want.

Comment: `str_replace('&yy=no&bb=525252','',$str)` doesn't work?

Comment: Use `parse_url()` to extract the query_string then you can `explode()` on `&` and just extract what you need from the array or key=value options.

Comment: ludesign's advice is probably best. Do you really want to depend on a specific order of parameters in a URL?

Comment: I second that. @ludesign's advice is the way I'd go. You'll end up with a lot of grief relying on regex to parse a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going for preg_replace was a good start. But you need to learn about [regexes](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

This will work:

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?&xx=okok&yy=no&bb=525252';
echo preg_replace ('/&yy.+$/', '', $str);
```

Here the regex is `&yy.+$`

Let's see how this works:

- `&yy` matches `&yy` obviously
- `.+` matches everything ...
- `$` ... until the end of the string.

So here, my replacement says : Replace whatever begins by `&yy` until the end of the string by *nothing*, which is actually simply deleting this part.

Comment: @WomarioSay If that fits your needs, don't forget to add an "accept" flag.

Comment: this is not what i need ... i need to remove all the rest
www.example.com/yyy/xxxxxx/blablbla.html
i want the result like that : www.example.com/yyy/xxxxxx/

Comment: @WomarioSay That wasn't your question. Feel free to post another one, and consider having a look at all the tools suggested instead of waiting for someone to give you the answer. (Regexes, parse_url, substring, explode)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$a = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?&xx=okok&yy=no&bb=525252';

$b = substr($a,0,strpos($a,'&yy')); // Set in '&yy' the string to identify the beginning of the string to remove

echo $b; // Will print http://www.example.com/index.php?&xx=okok
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you always expecting the end part to have the 'yy' variable name? You could try this:

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?&xx=okok&yy=no&bb=525252';
$ex = explode('&yy=', $str, 2);
$firstPart = $ex[0];
```